# Strange behaviour using StrUtils 'SearchBuf'

Tags: delphi

I am tidying old code that used to use FastStrings and I've implemented an old routine of mine 'PosAnyCase' which should operate like 'Pos'. (I was hoping that SearchBuf was better than calling UpperCase on both strings).

```
function PosAnyCase( const AFindStr, AStr : string ) : integer;
// Returns the position of this substring within a string ignoring case
```

I'm using SearchBuf as follows:

```
function PosAnyCase( const AFindStr, AStr : string ) : integer;
// Returns the position of this substring within a string ignoring case
var
  Start, ResultPos : PChar;
begin
  Start := PChar( AStr );

  ResultPos := SearchBuf(
    Start, ByteLength( AStr ),
    0, 0,
    AFindStr, [soDown] );

  if ResultPos = nil then
    Result := 0
   else
    Result := ResultPos-Start+1;
end;
```

When I call this routine from my unit tests, the following tests PASS:

```
  Check(
    PosAnyCase( '', '123' ) = 0 );
  Check(
    PosAnyCase( '2', '123' ) = 2 );
  Check(
    PosAnyCase( 'A', 'ABC' ) = 1 );
  Check(
    PosAnyCase( 'a', 'ABC' ) = 1 );
  Check(
    PosAnyCase( 'the', 'hellot there' ) = 8 );
  Check(
    PosAnyCase( 'THE', 'hellot there' ) = 8 );
```

But this test FAILS:

```
Check(
    PosAnyCase( 'nice', 'does not have n i c e' ) = 0 );
```

What am I doing wrong please? The documentation on SearchBuf is very limited....
Thanks

Comment: So, you expected the function to return zero, but instead it returned something else. What does it return? When you step through the failing case with the debugger, where do you see things go wrong?

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes I did try debugging it. 'ResultPos' (PChar) shows 'nice'. Weird. This then falls out of the routine as 29 which is longer than the string.

Comment: It's because the length is wrong, as I explained, and there is a buffer overrun which happens to find the other `'nice'`. Nice!

Comment: David, ah ByteLength! Yes, changing to Length sorts it. I thought the buffer was a buffer of bytes, even for Unicode. Duh! Thanks.

Comment: Documentation does say that you should pass length in bytes. Documentation is wrong. You followed it to the letter and it let you down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to `ByteLength` is incorrect. Although the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StrUtils.SearchBuf) explicitly states that the parameter is the length in bytes, that is not the case. You should use `Length` instead because the function actually expects units of `char` rather than units of `byte`.

Comment: They haven't yet fixed the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.StrUtils.SearchBuf)! I can't believe it.